# How would I make sure that data doesn't get lost if server crashes

Tags: c#, database, api, server

Say an example API controller that verifies JWT then takes a json data to create a transaction between users
In such a method, there would be multiple SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE that happen throughout the method execution, such as getting funds of user, pulling out funds to temp "wallet" then adding the funds to the receiver

Say method does db interactions like this: 1.SELECT -> 2.UPDATE -> 4.CREATE -> 5.SELECT -> 6.UPDATE -> SELECT

but if the server/application crashes at query n.4, the n.6 interaction will never be completed.

My question is: **How can I make sure that the method completes or reverts db to the initial state before the crash?**

My idea for this is to create a "snap" of the data i need in case there is a crash and then revert main table back to it's snap state. If possible a solution to handle switching back to that snap state and how to detect a server crash

Comment: Read up on DB transactions

Comment: What do you mean? I'm asking about how to ensure the data gets restored on crash without putting too many bandages in the code

Comment: Then you should read up about Transactions

Comment: Begin a transaction, do all your data writes/updates/deletes commit the transaction.  If the commit doesn't happen then the DB isn't actually updated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: ok thanks will read up on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I have used to introduce Transactional commits.

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec xyz");
        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /* Do something here with error */ }
}
```

You can also update the database or exceute multiple changes to the dbContext before you exit the using script block (that uses Transaction). All changes will only be committed when you run the dbContextTransaction.Commit() line. Otherwise, all changes will be rolled back if any error occurs.

[See MS Documentation on Transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions)